# Want to generate random numbers. simulating rolling dice

Tags: random, numbers, generator, dice

I am trying to load two arrays. representing the possible outcomes (1-6) of rolling dice. The first array gets loaded with the first dice outcome and the second array.....I am struggling with keeping both arrays in one loop that manages the amount of times the dice are rolled, and not generating the duplicate results. Believe i need to either re-seed between each roll, any help would be much appreciated.

Current output:
Dice one: 5 Dice two: 5
Dice one: 3 Dice two: 3
Dice one: 1 Dice two: 1
Dice one: 6 Dice two: 6
Dice one: 6 Dice two: 6
Dice one: 2 Dice two: 2
Dice one: 5 Dice two: 5
Dice one: 2 Dice two: 2
Dice one: 1 Dice two: 1
Dice one: 1 Dice two: 1
second roll always matches the first

I have written as follows:

```
int min = 1;
    int max = 6;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        Random rand;
        rand = new Random();

        int randomNumber = rand.nextInt(max) + min;
        diceOne[i] = randomNumber;
        System.out.print("Dice one: ");
        System.out.print(diceOne[i] + " ");


        int randomNumber2 = rand.nextInt(max) + min;

        diceTwo[i] = randomNumber2;
        System.out.print("Dice two: ");
        System.out.print(diceOne[i]);
        System.out.println();
```

Comment: Why are you re-initializing the RNG every loop?

Answer (score 1):

diceTwo is never use. try code below

```
 int randomNumber = rand.nextInt(max) + min;
            diceOne[i] = randomNumber;
            System.out.print("Dice one: ");
            System.out.print(diceOne[i] + " ");


            int randomNumber2 = rand.nextInt(max) + min;

            diceTwo[i] = randomNumber2;
            System.out.print("Dice two: ");
            System.out.print(diceTwo[i]); //System.out.print(diceOne[i]);
            System.out.println();
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much, as I am learning to program I have realized that sometimes the easiest problems to fix stump me the longest.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it looks like you are printing out `diceOne[i]` both times.